# Unable to use elastic search for indexing mysql table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, lucene, driver, elasticsearch

I want to index my mysql table using elasticsearch

I have followed this tutorials

```
https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart
```

I get the following message at the last

```
"error" : "IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]",
  "status" : 404
```

can someone please help